# delphi socket exception can't change value of host and port

Tags: sockets, delphi-7

while i am trying to assign port and host to delphi client socket, an exception is raised "Can't change value while socket is active". But i haven't changed the socket.active := true. Can anybody suggest possible cause of this error.

```
procedure CreateSocket(add : pchar);
var
  port : integer;
  address : string;
  host : string;
  socket1 : TClientSocket;
begin  
  setstring(address,add,50);
  //showmessage(address) ;
  host := split(address,':');
  address := del(address,':');
  //showmessage(address);
  port := strtoint(address);

  socket1.port := port; //exception comes here
  socket1.host := host;

  showmessage('address assigned');

  connectionAttempt(Socket1);

  CheckDataArrival(socket1);
end;
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You've already connected the socket somehow and are now trying to change the address:port.

Comment: @EJP no i dont.. i used different port no. to see that.

Comment: @Lizz i have added code to the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your actual copy/pasted code, then you have declared a `TClientSocket` variable but are not instantiating a `TClientSocket` object, so you are setting the host and port on invalid memory.

Comment: i added socket := Tclientsocket.create(nil) then it started working.